# Android, Chrome. URL address bar affecting image with max-width, in landscape

Tags: android, html, css

I have a simple, large image that I want to fit the width of the screen. The image is around 1600 pixels wide and has the `max-width:100%;` attribute so it should always fit the screen.

The problem appears on android's Chrome browser, when the URL bar slides down, after scrolling, the image is no longer 100% and is off by a % or 2. This only appears when the device is landscape, portrait mode is fine.

What is it about the address bar that is affecting the scale of my image?

**Edit: If max-height/width takes into account screen space including the address bar, how does one get the same responsive image effect as with the use of max-width/height.**

**CSS**

```
div.lndContainer {
    max-height:750px;
    max-width:1600px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-top:50px;
}
div.lndContainer img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="lndContainer">
    <img width="1600" height="750" src="http://lart.co.uk/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/cats-q-g-1600-750-6.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because max-height / max-width is related to the actual space for the webpage (in this case the space without the url bar).

And why? If you want to use fixed elements (css-> position:fixed;) that are at the top or at the bottom of the view, a minimied viewport because the urlbar is there will cause that you cannot see the top or the bottom element anymore, which can't be shown by scrolling.

Comment: Thanks Tom, so what should I do if I want responsive images that keep the correct scale? Why does this only happen in landscape?

Comment: @UzumakiDev I think the only way is to use pixels. To get the screen with and height, you can use JavaScript and add an amount of pixels for the url bar. But as the url bar is shown, the image will be scrollen down, and this is something where i don't know a way.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I'll give you the tick as it answered the core of my question. Now I have more questions :D

Comment: just setting height to auto fixed my problem :)